# Text Local code not working on another machine

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

I am using Text Local API in my project to create broadcast SMS feature.
Following is the code chunk for showing how I have coded.

```
// Email Address 
public $emailAddress = "******.********.com";

// Sender Id
public $senderId = "TXTLCL";

// API Hash key
public $APIKey = "*************************";

// Mobiles Numbers
public $mobileNumbers = array();

...
...

 $this->capturedResponse = $textLocalObj->sendSms($this->mobileNumbers, $this->messageText, $this->senderId);

...
...
```

Now the issue is that the code which works fine on my local machine does not work on other's local machine and even on the production server, it does not work.

Please help!!!

Comment: what does the `error_log` on production say?

Comment: there is no error. in fact, the captured response is positive and the SMS balance is also available. only the issue is sms is not sent to the numbers from the other's local machine and production server.